# How to upload a file to google drive api with a different name than untitled

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-drive-api

This is the structure of my code, I tried to send the name in the object "formData.append", but I have not been successful.

The documentation indicates: send on the body.

Documentation Links:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create -
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#http_1

I got this answer.

{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "1uz_NN-IyoiPzaheAiKIJu6qlB7ZfxIX2",
"name": "Untitled",
"mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

Name: "Untitled"

*- I will be grateful*

```js
Upload.prototype.doUpload = function () {
        var that = this;
        var formData = new FormData();
    
        formData.append("file", this.file);
        formData.append("upload_file", true);
        formData.append("name", "test_file");
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
                
            },
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files",
            data:{
                uploadType:"multipart"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            async: true,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            timeout: 60000
        });
    };
```

Comment: Copying that response into the question would increase its quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- It seems that ajax cannot be directly request with `multipart/form-data` using `FormData()`. So in this case, it is required to create the structure of `multipart/form-data` and send it as the data.

  - In your script, only the file content is uploaded without the file metadata. By this, the uploaded file has no filename. In this case, it is required to upload the file content and file metadata with `multipart/form-data`.
- In your script, there are 2 properties of `data`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
Upload.prototype.doUpload = function () {
    const file = this.file;  // It supposes that "this.file" is the blob.

    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    fr.onload = function() {
      const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
      let data = "--" + boundary + "\n";
      data += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n\n";
      data += JSON.stringify({name: "test_file"}) + "\n";
      data += "--" + boundary + "\n";
      data += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
      data += fr.result.split(",")[1] + "\n";
      data += "--" + boundary + "--";
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(request) {
          request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
          request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary);
        },
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        async: true,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        timeout: 60000
      });
    }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script,

  - It supposes that `this.file` in your script is the blob.
  - Your access token can be used for uploading the file to Google Drive.
- When `uploadType=multipart` is used, the maximum file size is 5 MB. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked for me perfectly, for uploadType=resumable 
what would be necessary?, change the type but it's not enough, I appreciate to understand the differences.

Comment: @Vilmcode Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the resumable upload of `uploadType=resumable`, the upload process is different from `uploadType=media` and `uploadType=multipart`. Please check [the official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable). When you have the issue of your script for the resumable upload, please post it as new question. By this, it will be help users including me think of the solution.